# How can I press “Insert” on a keyboard without that key?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, hotkeys

I have lenovo flex. It does not have numpad. I am using ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely at your keyboard, you can see that there is a button dedicated to <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

[image: Lenovo Flex Keyboard]
<sup>Image by [PC Perspective](https://pcper.com/reviews/Mobile/Lenovo-IdeaPad-Flex-14-Convertible-Ultrabook-Review-Affordable-Convertible)</sup>

As you can see from the picture in the bottom right, the <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key has <kbd>Insert</kbd> as secondard function, accessed by the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

In order to use it, press the combination <kbd>Fn + PgDn</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `Insert` key on all the pictures of the Lenovo Flex I could find (top row of keys, to the right, actual position depending a bit on the Flex model).

Comment: You can use the `<kbd>`-tag for keyboard keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an PRT SC (print screen) key and a FN (function) key, press and hold the 'fn' key and then press the 'prt sc' key, and then release both at the same time. This should toggle the insert on or off. Sometimes the 'prt sc' key has the letters 'ins' on it as well.

Comment: https://c1.neweggimages.com/productimage/AAD0_1_20160708522617326.jpg
Print screen button does not have secondary function on function key. What I really need is to switch functionality of a key may be right ctrl button to insert key.